# psycopg2 error on Google App Engine

Tags: python, postgresql, google-app-engine, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm hosting a website/app using Flask/SQLAlchemy on Google's App Engine, part of which entails communicating with a PostgreSQL server and querying it to populate the website. 
The SQL server is hosted on Google's Compute Engine as a VM instance per [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres), but with the server open to all connections.

When I send a GET request to the website/app when it is hosted on localhost, I get the data I expect. However, when I launch the app and attempt to send the same request to the new URL, I get an HTTP 500 error. In GCP's logging section, I see the request and a stack trace containing the following:

```
 (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:279)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/main.py", line 108, in get_book1
    for item in models.Book.query.all():
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 498, in __get__
    return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 78, in __call__
    return self.registry()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 990, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2829, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 145, in __init__
    bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 922, in engine
    return self.get_engine()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 941, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 543, in get_engine
    self._engine = rv = sqlalchemy.create_engine(info, **options)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 387, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 80, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 554, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cs373-idb/20170411t063743.400476890985925133/lib/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_psycopg)
```

Given dummy data (i.e., having the app return some set data as opposed to querying the database,) the GET requests work fine, and TravisCI has no problem running tests which also involve querying the database using the same source, so I'm confident that the problem is with the database and its interaction with GAE.

I've read seemingly conflicting articles on Google's own website on whether or not PostgreSQL is supported by the App Engine. Is there a way to solve this?

If it helps, this is the lib folder that I've set for the app:

```
aniso8601                  flask                           itsdangerous.py         MarkupSafe-1.0.dist-info         requests-2.13.0.dist-info          SQLAlchemy-1.1.9.dist-info
aniso8601-1.2.0.dist-info  Flask-0.12.1.dist-info          itsdangerous.pyc        psycopg2                         requests_toolbelt                  werkzeug
click                      flask_restful                   jinja2                  psycopg2-2.7.1.dist-info         requests_toolbelt-0.7.1.dist-info  Werkzeug-0.12.1.dist-info
click-6.7.dist-info        Flask_RESTful-0.3.5.dist-info   Jinja2-2.9.6.dist-info  python_dateutil-2.6.0.dist-info  six-1.10.0.dist-info
coverage                   flask_sqlalchemy                markup                  pytz                             six.py
coverage-4.3.4.dist-info   Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.2.dist-info  markup-0.2.dist-info    pytz-2017.2.dist-info            six.pyc
dateutil                   itsdangerous-0.24.dist-info     markupsafe              requests                         sqlalchemy
```

These libraries were added from GCP's console with the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib
```

where requirements.txt contains this list:

```
Flask
Flask-SQLAlchemy
psycopg2
Markup
requests
flask_restful
requests-toolbelt
coverage
```

Finally, my python version is 2.7.9 and pip 9.0.1

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this. Any advice would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Wow.. I know this is a very old thread but I'm seeing the same on Google App Engine trying to connect to PostgreSQL. Any idea?

Comment: @strangetimes Yeah, I was using SQLAlcgemy to try to connect to Postgres too. I eventually worked around it by hosting the SQL server on GCP (using their SQL platform, NOT their VMs) let me know if you have questions, maybe I can help.

Comment: did you use the flex environment? I tried switching to mysql on the standard environment but it seems too restrictive

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres

Comment: This link just about covers it. App Engine only supports Postgres connections through its native CloudSQL platform

Comment: Do you guys know if I can connect to an external postgresql cluster hosted in a third party service?