# Flask returning 500 on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm very new to flask & Google App Engine. I'm able to run this locally fine and it's building/deploying fine on Google, but when I hit the URL it returns a 500. Nothing shows up in the error logs, when I view the logs for the path im testing ('/'), I can see some errors.

main.py:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS

# instantiated flask application
app = Flask(__name__) # __name__ is the name of the module
CORS(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mydb'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    results = db.session.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
    print('got results', results)
    users = [{"name": "sam"}]
    # for r in results:
    #     new = {
    #         "user_id": r['user_id']
    #     }
    #     users.append(new)

    return jsonify(users)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0
Flask-Cors==3.0.3
psycopg2==2.5.2
```

I didn't originally include psycopg2 in my requirements, but i saw Google complaining it couldn't find the module. I thought maybe flask-sqlalchemy is using it?

Anyways, now it is saying:

> ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function
>   (init_psycopg)
>
> 2019-08-02 09:25:52.287 CDT
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py:835:
>   FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant
>   overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to
>   True or False to suppress this warning. 2019-08-02 09:25:52.287 CDT
>   'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
>   2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT [2019-08-02 14:25:52,448] ERROR in app:
>   Exception on / [GET] 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT Traceback (most
>   recent call last): 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/flask/app.py",
>   line 1982, in wsgi_app 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request() 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/flask/app.py",
>   line 1614, in full_dispatch_request 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/flask/app.py",
>   line 1517, in handle_user_exception 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/flask/app.py",
>   line 1612, in full_dispatch_request 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       rv = self.dispatch_request() 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/flask/app.py",
>   line 1598, in dispatch_request 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/main.py",
>   line 21, in hello_world 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       results = db.session.execute('SELECT * FROM users') 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py",
>   line 162, in do 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs) 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/sqlalchemy/util/*collections.py",
>   line 1012, in **call** 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc()) 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 3214, in **call** 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       return self.class*(**local_kw) 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 138, in **init** 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 937, in engine 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       return self.get_engine() 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 956, in get_engine 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       return connector.get_engine() 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 561, in get_engine 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       self._engine = rv = self._sa.create_engine(sa_url, options) 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 966, in create_engine 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       return sqlalchemy.create_engine(sa_url, **engine_opts) 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/**init**.py",
>   line 435, in create_engine 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs) 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py",
>   line 87, in create 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args) 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 653, in dbapi 2019-08-02 09:25:52.462 CDT
>       import psycopg2 2019-08-02 09:25:52.463 CDT   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~flaskappevents/20190802t092443.420035961696766896/lib/psycopg2/**init**.py",
>   line 50, in  2019-08-02 09:25:52.463 CDT
>       from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID 2019-08-02 09:25:52.463 CDT ImportError: dynamic module does not
>   define init function (init_psycopg) 2019-08-02 09:25:52.473 CDT This
>   request caused a new process to be started for your application, and
>   thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time.
>   This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical
>   request for your application.

Comment: What's the plan with SQLAlchemy? what are you using as your DB?

Comment: I had issues getting psycopg2 to install on my machine, so I’m using SQLAlchemy. It’s a Postgres dB hosted through heroku. It’s connecting fine in the code on my Mac.

Comment: you'll have an easier time if you have your postgres DB within Google Cloud SQL https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quickstart. In the comments on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342835/psycopg2-error-on-google-app-engine they say `App Engine only supports Postgres connections through its native CloudSQL platform` However that question is a bit old, so its possible that things are different now. Another option is using App Engine Flex instead of App Engine Standard.

Comment: My understanding is that there is a cost associated with using CloudSQL solutions. I also found this page (one exists for flexible as well) that is saying third party connections are possible https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/using-third-party-databases

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar case here [Google App Engine Import Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234503/google-appengine-importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-init) and the problem was that in the app.yaml file it was missing the type of DB. The user there, it was using MySQLdb but I think you can try the solution given in the link with SQLAlchemy.